# AdventureWorks2012: SQL Determine the total number of products EVER and NEVER been sold like in one data set

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am a student and spend enough time to get this done . Can someone help me with this 
Ques is: Determine the total number of products ever have been sold and total number of product never have been sold like in one data set.

I guess Union , Intersection and Except ill be used on Production.Product and sales.salesOrderDetail.

Can someone plz help me

Comment: do you mean a count of the products that have been sold and a count of the products that have never been sold?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly then this should work

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.ProductId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalProductsUnsold
    , SUM(CASE WHEN s.ProductId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) TotalProductsSold
FROM Production.Product p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ProductId
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
) s ON s.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

Using union and except you could do something like

```
SELECT 
    'Total Products Unsold'
    , COUNT(ProductId) [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT
        ProductId
    FROM Production.Product 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ProductId
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
) Products
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total Products Sold'
    , COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId) [Count]
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

If you can't use / don't want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` then the second unioned select statement can be replaced with

```
SELECT 
    'Total Products Unsold'
    , COUNT(ProductId) [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT
        ProductId
    FROM Production.Product 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ProductId
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
) Products
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked. Can we somehow do it  using UNION also. I am suppose to demonstrate union in this query.